# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar mi app que esta en Laravel por medio de una API?

Tags: php, laravel, api, update

Explico con ejemplo para detallar mas mi pregunta de lo que quiero hacer:

--- Hay varias instalaciones de mi app en diferentes servidores, en la app hay un opción que dice "actualizar app", donde ingresar el numero de licencia y este se conecta a un server a través de una API donde se encuentra la app central con la versión mas reciente...

Este responda con las actualizaciones que debe realizarse, por ejemplo, si tenia un controlador con 2 métodos, y ahora la actualización implementa 4 métodos a ese controlador, entonces, borra y crea de nuevo el controlador o reescribe el controlador... así realizar las actualizaciones correspondientes ---

Esto es lo que quisiera hacer, pero no encuentro documentación para la gestión de archivos de la app como la modificación de los controladores, modelos, etc... a través de la API.

Solo he encontrado como actualizar Laravel, pero no quiero actualizar Laravel sino la lógica de la app.

Donde o como se llama el tema para poder realizar esto...? O que me recomiendan para realizar esta lógica, gracias de antemano!!

Comment: sé a lo que te refieres con tu pregunta, pero una alternativa es conectarte vía ftp al servidor y ahí cargar tu carpeta de laravel, esto va a generar que el programa que estés usando te pregunte para actualizar los archivos y al darle que si , va a actualizar tus controladores y demases, espero te sirva como opción. saludos

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda gracias por el comentario, pero no seria por API, sino que manualmente YO tendria que conectarme a cada server y actualizar vdd?... Lo que busco es que el administrador de la app actualice sin que YO y otro desarrolladores intervengan, es decir, el administrador busque la actualizacion y se ejecute las instrucciones que respondio la API... gracias amigo!!